# Fedora 17 - Not able to restart my network service

Tags: networking, fedora

I am using fedora 17. Whenever i try to restart my network service using sudo /etc/init.d/network restart i get the following error. (NetworkManager enabled and disabled properly) -->

Restarting network (via systemctl):  Job failed. See system journal and 'systemctl status' for details.
                                                           [FAILED]

how i can successfully restart my network service ?

Comment: You are apparently using NetworkManager which controls your network connections.  Perhaps you want to restart the NetworkManager via 'service NetworkManager restart' (or the systemctl command)?

Comment: i tried using both methods.. it didnt work... !

Comment: Perhaps some background would help here.  Why are you restarting your network service?  What was the error message for `service NetworkManager restart`?

Comment: my ip was assigned as "dhcp". i assigned it statically and tried restarting network service. service NetworkManager restart is running fine without error. problem with sudo /etc/init.d/network restart. It was giving error as above.

Comment: Ah, since you're using NetworkManager, use it to assign the static IP and then you'll have no need to restart anything.  NetworkManager should take care of everything for you.